# Standard Deviation of certain cells in excel

Tags: excel, deviation

for eg I have 5 numbers in excel,   in A1,A2 etc    numbers could be 95 99 98 96 97,  (not sorted).  How do I get the standard deviation for the top 4 numbers only (ie: dropping the lowest number)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
=STDEV.S(FILTER(A:A,A:A>SMALL(A:A,1)))
```

[image]